# Clarifying interaction of SSL, DNS, webserver

Tags: node.js, dns, http-headers, ssl-certificate

Please forgive the wishy washy nature of this question, I'm unsure how better to phrase it.

I have a nodejs server which will be accessed (HTTP + websockets) through a variety of third party DNSs by the third parties adding a new A record in their DNS entry pointing at my IP. I can find the origination third party DNS name by looking at the request headers. Node is then acting as a proxy and ultimately modifying the request headers/adding metadata before forwarding the request back to another url at the third party.

Could anyone explain please how SSL/TLS operates when the third party certificate is a wildcard cert for the origination DNS; how is the chain of encryption carried to node -> do I need to host a copy of the third party certificate on the node server? (Obviously I'd rather not). Can I use a third party's original SSL set up to any advantage?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS and HTTPS are fairly unrelated here. The client only uses DNS to find the web server's IP address. After that, the http protocol contains the Host name it is requesting in the `Host` header, as you have determined.

Your server will need an HTTPS certificate for each **Host** name that is will handle requests for, otherwise browsers will not be able to make a trusted connection to it. The certificate says "This server is authorized to handle requests for this host name".

In practice, though DNS and HTTPS are related, because if you control dns, you can issue a certificate. [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) has made this very easy to set up.

I would not recommend sharing certificates with third parties, as that can be a bit of a pain, and it is harder to keep private keys secure if you are emailing them back and forth or something. Just issue your own certs for the third-party domains you need to serve.

My personal favorite solution for a case like yours is running a [caddy](https://cadyserver.com) server instance in front of my app to manage https certificates automatically, and proxy requests to your node backend. It can even [issue certs dynamically](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#on-demand) as it receives requests.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, makes much more sense now. Bloody hell Caddy looks awesome! I've been using let's encrypt but didn't realise this could be done so seamlessly, thank you!